# Resize uploaded images for better viewing

Tags: java, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I have a profile picture which i stored in database in a byte[] field.

What I want do is to create image thumbnails at runtime. Because I have to show images in different sizes on different place on a web page. Something like facebook, which show image in a comment section and other areas.

Any grails plugin which i can use, i have google imageTool, imageMagick grails plugin. Anyone can recommend the plugin for any other approach to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a `grails` plugin that you can use.

See this [ImageTools plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/image-tools)

After installing the plugin you may use following statement to generate thumbnail of desired size

Or if its a thin app and you dont want external dependencies.. you may use the following code [Source](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Image-thumbnail-td1345316.html)

```
import java.awt.Image as AWTImage 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage 
import javax.swing.ImageIcon 
import javax.imageio.ImageIO as IIO 
import java.awt.Graphics2D 

  static resize = { bytes, out, maxW, maxH -> 
      AWTImage ai = new ImageIcon( bytes ).image 
      int width = ai.getWidth( null ) 
      int height = ai.getHeight( null ) 

      def limits = 300..2000 
      assert limits.contains( width ) && limits.contains( height ) : 'Picture is either too small or too big!'   

      float aspectRatio = width / height 
      float requiredAspectRatio = maxW / maxH 

      int dstW = 0 
      int dstH = 0 
      if( requiredAspectRatio < aspectRatio ){ 
        dstW = maxW 
        dstH = Math.round(  maxW / aspectRatio ) 
      }else{ 
        dstH = maxH 
        dstW = Math.round( maxH * aspectRatio ) 
      } 

      BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage( dstW, dstH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB ) 
      Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics() 
      g2d.drawImage( ai, 0, 0, dstW, dstH, null, null ) 

      IIO.write( bi, 'JPEG', out ) 

  }
```

Comment: What about imageMagick, do you recommend this plugin ?

Comment: @UmairSaleem : Never used imageMagick. So no comments.